# Reading/writing C arrays from R matrices

Tags: c, r, wrapper

Below is a **minimal example of creating 3 matrices in R that should be manipulated by calling C code**.

In short, I'd like to pass a matrix A from R to C, which then copies some values to the W and H matrices. The latter 2 I want back in R with the modified values.

However, this doesn't quite work (**segfault, or empty matrices returned**). I suspect that R copies the objects for use in C instead of passing them by reference.

C source (test.c):

```
void test(double *A, double *W, double *H, int m, int n, int k) {
    // A is input with dimensions (m,n)
    // W has dimensions (m,k)
    // H has dimensions (k,n)

    int i;

    for(i=0; i<m*k; i++)
        W[i] = A[i];

    for(i=0; i<k*n; i++)
        H[i] = A[i];
}
```

Some build instructions (Makefile):

```
CCFLAGS = -fPIC

all: shared

shared: test.o
    $(CC) -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -o test.so test.o

test.o: test.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $<
```

And that's the R code to call it:

```
dyn.load("test.so")

m = 3
n = 3
k = 2

A = matrix(c(1:(m*n)), nrow=m, ncol=n)

W = matrix(0, nrow=m, ncol=k)
H = matrix(0, nrow=k, ncol=n)

.C("test", as.double(A), as.double(W), as.double(H), 
   as.integer(m), as.integer(n), as.integer(k))
```

Now my questions:

- Why does this segfault most of the time?
- Is there a way to call C functions with uninitialized R matrices?
- Why does a 'void' function return something?

And, most importantly,

- How to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why does this segfault most of the time?

This is (probably) because your function takes integers, whereas, the `.C` interface will pass in pointers.  Your signature should be

```
void test(double *A, double *W, double *H, int *m, int *n, int *k)
```

- Is there a way to call C functions with uninitialized R matrices?

Setting `DUP=FALSE` in your call to `.C` will prevent `.C` from copying the arrays you pass into it.  See `?.C` for details.

- Why does a 'void' function return something?

The C function doesn't return anything, but the R function `.C` returns a list, corresponding the the arguments passed in to the C function.  Again, see `?.C`.

- How to get this working?

You have two choices.  The first is to set `DUP=FALSE` and let the C function modify the existing R objects.  If you do this, though, you want to make sure that you call `as.double` before you pass them into the external call, otherwise `as.double` will be forced to create new objects, because as currently defined `W` and `H` will be type integer.

Your second choice is to leave `DUP=TRUE`, and use the return value from the `.C` call, as in:

```
result<-.C("test", as.double(A), W=as.double(W), H=as.double(H), 
  as.integer(m), as.integer(n), as.integer(k))
W<-result$W
H<-result$H
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! (just have to reshape W and H into the right form again)